# How do you remove a class that matches a pattern from the class attribute, but retain the other classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, class-attributes

I want to delete the classes that end with 'blue' from the class attribute on all tags

sample html

```
<p class="text_blue happy">this is blue text</p>
<p class="text_red nothappy">this is red text</p>
<img class="img_blue nothappy" />
```

This will give me all the elements with classes that end with 'blue'

```
$('[class$=blue]');
```

how do I pop these matched classnames off of the class attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pull the whole class name out with a regular expression like this:

```
$('[class$="blue"]').each(function() {
    var clsName = this.className.match(/\w*blue\w*/)[0];
});
```

One thing that you should realize is that `$('[class$="blue"]')` operates on the entire attribute named `class`.  I does not operate on individual class names.  So, it will match:

```
class="happy text_blue"
```

But, it will not match:

```
class="text_blue happy"
```

because the class attribute does not end with `"blue"`.  If you want it to get any class name that contains `"blue"` regardless of where it is positioned in the class name attribute, you would have to use:

```
$('[class*="blue"]').each(function() {
    var clsName = this.className.match(/\w*blue\w*/)[0];
});
```

If you further wanted to filter out class names that did not end with blue, you could do that with JS like this:

```
$('[class*="blue"]').each(function() {
    var match = this.className.match(/\w*blue(\b|$)/);
    if (match) {
        var clsName = match[0];
    }
});
```

If you want to remove these class names from the objects, you could do it like this:

```
$('[class*="blue"]').each(function() {
    var match = this.className.match(/\w*blue(\b|$)/);
    if (match) {
        $(this).removeClass(match[0]);
    }
});
```

It could also be done this way which seems a little cleaner, but it doesn't perfectly clean up extra whitespace around the class name it's removing:

```
$('[class*="blue"]').each(function() {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/\w*blue(\b|$)/, "").replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be doing this a lot, you might want to change how you assign classes.  You can make your HTML like this:

```
<p class="text blue happy">this is blue text</p>
```

and then instead of using a selector of `.text_blue` in your CSS, use `.text.blue` instead.  Then you can simply remove "blue" from the classes.

Comment: ah I got accustomed to not chaining classes like that because IE6 didnt support that, guess that doesnt matter anymore! Good point though. Regardless, is there a way to do what Im asking?